# Bigquery Custom first day of week (defaults Monday)

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to extract week from date using the function

> format_timestamp('%V', DATE)

but Bigquery documentation says "Monday as the first day of the week".

Is there a way where I can specify Tuesday as first day of week.

I have achieved the same in Redshift using

> date_part(week, date + interval '-1 day')

Is it possible in Bigquery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

You can use [WEEK(WEEKDAY)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#extract) as shown below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%V', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), 
EXTRACT(WEEK(SATURDAY) FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
```

This was introduced quite recently - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#november_30_2017

Comment: Thanks Mikhail :). Exactly the function I was looking for. But I think Bigquery  developers has screwed it up. For e.g. If I set week start day to saturday. Then 2017-01-06 is week 0, 2017-01-07 is Week 1, 2017-01-08 is Week1, Where as 2017-01-09 is Week2. Absolutely no clue how they get this number

Comment: On the go now. Will get back to you shortly :o)

Comment: Mikhail, ignore my previous comment. I think I got it how It is implemented. But I am looking for ISOWEEK instead of returning 0. I see that there is ISOWEEK function but it doesn't accept week start day as parameter

Comment: you can submit feature request if you wish - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0

Comment: Great they rejected it straight away saying intended behavior

Comment: What is the default weekday if no weekday specified? The docs don't currently state.

Comment: @crazy8 - from [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#extract) - `WEEK: Returns the week number of the date in the range [0, 53]. Weeks begin with Sunday, and dates prior to the first Sunday of the year are in week 0`